# How to compare two strings with conditions?

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have a paragraph which contains author name like:

> Gopi, K.P., and Vijay, S. (1997) Computer Controlled Systems: Theory
>   and Design, Third edition, Mc Graw-Hill, ND Cliffs, IND.

and another paragraph like this:

> It will cause numerical difficulty (Gopi and Vijay, 1997). What’s
>   more, when the process constraints are activated, the significant
>   deterioration of closed-loop control performance will be clearly
>   witnessed as kind of nonlinearity is dominating the control system
>   (Tenny, Rawlings, and Wright, 2004).

So how to compare these two paragraph with the multiple author name (Gopi & vijay) with the year of publication.

**Note:** In the first reference part all the format styling of author name with year information is constant.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `How to compare these two strings?` what do you want as a return value?

Comment: I split the two paragraph into streamsplitter and i use the conditions like every author name ended with comma, and Year information ended with full stop likewise but i struggled here is splitting string into two strings is made. How both the condition (Author name and year info) need to put in a single condition?

Comment: In a single paragraph i need to get two string values (author name & year) and how it will compare with new paragraph? and the result is string matched as a output message

Answer (score 2):

A "compare" (between those strings) provides three possible results:

- the first string is "greater" than the second
- the first string is "less" than the second
- the two strings are "identical"

The meaning of "greater", "less" and "identical" depends of the comparison function.

You probably don't want a "compare". What does "the second paragraph is less than the first" even mean?
You are probably interested in finding out where the reference to "Computer Controlled Systems" is used in the text. (Something which should be trivial to do if the paper was referenced properly...)

If this is what you actually need, then it's time to figure out how would you, as a human, handle this task.

My first approach would be to take the reference string

```
string str = "Gopi, K.P., and Vijay, S. (1997) Computer Controlled Systems";
```

and see what is actually relevant in it

```
string[] substrings = str.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '(', ')' });
```

A paragraph referencing this "Computer Controlled Systems" source would be likely to contain "Gopi and Vijay, 1997" somewhere in it.

```
string toFind = substrings[0] + " and " + substrings[5] + ", " + substrings[9];
```

Then, I'd open the text in my favorite text viewer and search for "Gopi and Vijay, 1997".

```
string text = "It will cause numerical difficulty (Gopi and Vijay, 1997). What’s more, when the process constraints are activated, the significant deterioration of closed-loop control performance will be clearly witnessed as kind of nonlinearity is dominating the control system (Tenny, Rawlings, and Wright, 2004).";

int pos = text.IndexOf(toFind);
```

And then I'd store both the position of the match and a bit of context somewhere.

```
string match = "[...]" + text.Substring(Math.Max(pos - 50, 0), Math.Min(text.Length - pos, pos + toFind.Length + 50)) + "[...]";
```

Then, I would start looking at a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) because I would realize that there may be other combinations of "Gopi", "Vijay", "1997" and punctuation marks that may be used in the text.